# Selecting * from two tables using php and mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, one is projects, and the other is users.

```
PROJECTS table
ID     |     USER_ID    |   NAME
-------------------------------------
80     |        1       |   ABC Co.
82     |        2       |   XYZ Inc.

USERS table
ID     |     FIRSTNAME  |   LASTNAME
-------------------------------------
1      |     Joe        |   Namath
2      |     Jimmy      |   Fallon
```

What I want is to write a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM PROJECTS, USERS WHERE PROJECTS.USER_ID=USERS.ID AND FIRSTNAME = "Joe"
```

I can successfully run the query in php, but when I attempt to access the results, I don't get what I want.  I understand why, but I can't figure out a way to correct it.  For example:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_query($awesomeDatabaseLink);
echo $row['ID];  //returns '1' and I really wanted '80'
```

I get it.  The two tables have fields with the same name, but it's not the same data.  MySQL returns its best guess at what I so ambiguously asked for.  However, I have also tried:

```
echo $row['PROJECTS.ID']; //returns an empty string.
```

I should mention that I desperately need "*" from both tables. The Projects table has dozens and dozens of fields (not my design, and re-engineering the database is out-of-scope).  The Users table is also very extensive, so listing each field individually is much more impractical than it would appear by looking at my example tables.

Any suggestions?
SH

Comment: Use column alias instead

Comment: @1000111: Can I?  Even if I still need * from both tables and they are both far more complex than as shown here?  Can I do `SELECT *, USERS.ID UID FROM...`?

Comment: you can do like this `SELECT PROJECTS.*, USERS.ID FROM ....`

Comment: OK, but I need `USERS.*` too

Comment: Look at the answers please.

Comment: I did, but perhaps I still don't understand.  Your suggestion was going to return `PROJECTS.*, USERS.ID`   My code already does that, and when I try to access `$row['ID']` it can't tell if I want ID from Projects or Users.  I need some way to alias just one of the many fields that I need.

Comment: By the way, I didn't give the answer. The answer is already there. Please check the answer given by Object Manipulator guy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quickest fix is to assign a unique column alias for the expression (in this case just a simple column reference).

When you do that, you will need to qualify the `*` with the table name or alias. If you want to return *all* of the columns from both tables, you will need to included a `*` for each table.

Also, ditch the old-school comma operator for the join operation, and use the JOIN keyword instead. And qualify *all* column references.   For example:

```
SELECT PROJECTS.*
     , USERS.*
     , PROJECTS.ID AS MY_PROJECTS_ID
  FROM PROJECTS
  JOIN USERS
    ON USERS.ID=PROJECTS.USER_ID
   AND USERS.FIRSTNAME = "Joe"
```

The assigned alias `MY_PROJECTS_ID` will be the name of the column in the result set, so you reference that column by the assigned alias.

This assumes that there are no other columns being returned with the name `MY_PROJECTS_ID`.

Anytime there are two (or more) columns in the resultset that have the same name, you'll only get one of those columns referencing it by name.

Comment: My preference is to *not* use `*` in the SELECT list, and to list the specific columns (assigning aliases). There's a couple of reasons for that. 1) for the future reader, I think it makes it easier, they can see all of the columns being returned, without having to lookup table definitions 2) the code usually only needs a subset of columns, and there's potential for improved performance, not returning values that aren't needed.

Comment: And when I need painfully long list of columns from a table included in the SELECT list of a query I'm writing, I don't type it all out, I use the database to help me.  I run a query something like this: " `SELECT CONCAT('    , p.',c.column_name,'   AS p_',c.column_name) AS cols FROM information_schema.columns c WHERE c.table_schema = 'mydatabase' and c.table_name = 'mytable' ORDER BY c.ordinal_position` " and then copy resultset from that and paste it in my code, to help me write the SQL query I need.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to use alias. That'd make things less ambiguous.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
PROJECTS.ID AS project_id, 
USER_ID, 
NAME, 
USERS.ID AS user_id, 
FIRSTNAME, 
LASTNAME 
FROM PROJECTS, USERS 
WHERE PROJECTS.USER_ID=USERS.ID AND FIRSTNAME = "Joe"
```

And then:

```
echo $row['project_id']; //returns Project id
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

When you select stuff from multiple tables you should always qualify the names (give the full path, like `table.column`). If two tables share a column name then you need to give them different names.

```
SELECT u.ID AS UserId,
       u.FIRSTNAME AS FirstName,
       u.LASTNAME AS LastName,
       p.ID AS ProjectId,
       p.NAME AS ProjectName
FROM   USERS AS u
JOIN   PROJECTS AS p ON p.USER_ID = u.ID
WHERE  u.FIRSTNAME = "Joe"
```

If you want to get every column, but some of their names clash, then you can just rename the ones that clash, like so:

```
SELECT *,
       u.ID as USERID,
       p.ID as PROJECTID
FROM   USERS AS u
JOIN   PROJECTS AS p ON p.USER_ID = u.ID
WHERE  u.FIRSTNAME = "Joe"
```

Comment: Thank you, but that would take me forever.  U has heaps of columns, P has heaps and heaps.   There's got to be something more practical.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Using single SQL</title>
<style>
table,td,th
{
 padding:10px;
 border-collapse:collapse;
 font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
 border:solid #ddd 2px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table align="center" border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>product id</th>
<th>product name</th>
<th>category name</th>
</tr>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root");
mysql_select_db("dbtuts");
$res=mysql_query("SELECT c.* , p.* FROM tbl_categories c,tbl_products p WHERE c.cat_id=p.cat_id");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
 ?>
    <tr>
    <td><p><?php echo $row['product_id']; ?></p></td>
    <td><p><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></p></td>
    <td><p><?php echo $row['cat_name']; ?></p></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

follow this [link] (http://www.codingcage.com/2014/12/fetch-data-from-multiple-tables-in-php.html)!

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this doesn't help because p.id <> u.id, where your example was c.cat_id=p.cat_id.  It's not the same data.  project.user_id = user.id.  My code is returning the ID of the user table, and I need the ID from the project table.